# jquery-when error occur window scroll to specific place

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a form with many input field, when i submit validation error occur on top before a form.My question is when error message validation error occur how to make window scroll to `div#msg` where  my cursor in a bottom of page?

```
<div id="msg"><ol></ol></div>
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field1"/>
    <input type="text" name="field2"/>
    <input type="text" name="field3"/>
    ...
    <input type="text" name="fieldn"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$().ready(function() {

var options = { 
    success:       showResponse
    }; 

var container = $('#msg');
var validator = $("#myform").validate({
    messages: {
        field1: {
            required: "message",
        },
        fieldn: {
            required: "message",
        },
    },
    errorContainer: container,
    errorLabelContainer: $("ol", container),
    submitHandler: function(form) {
            jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
    },
    wrapper: 'li',
    meta: "validate",   
});

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 
          alert(responseText);
          validator.resetForm();
} 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a jQuery animate function call into your callback function `showResponse` were it returns your validation errors.

Try:

`$("html,body").animate({scrollTop:$('div#msg').offset().top}, 500);`

Comment: function showresponse show when a validation is success, not when a validation errors.